# unable to get all the key values in angular material expandable table

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have a json like this below

```
[
  { naming: 'Captain America', 
     city:[
      {"status":"inactive","age":30}
      ] 
  },
  { naming: 'Ironman', 
     bio:[
      {"area":"usa","gender":"male"}
      ] 
  }  

];
```

i am trying to create a expandable panel using angular material here the issue i am able the  "naming" keys and but i am not able to view the another key details int it i mean in the 1st object i have "city" as key and in the second object i have bio as key.

here how can i render the data in those keys dynamically so that i can display those keys and values side by side
below is my code

```
<mat-accordion>

    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let value of avengers">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            {{value.naming}}
      
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let x of value.city">
            {{x}}
       </ng-container>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion> 
<hr>
```

stackblitz url :-- > https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-expansion-panel-5ragqy

Comment: Have you seen the solution I provide for your issue ? Is it helping you ? Feel free to tell me if something is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a little Pipe to get your different keys of your object

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
    return Object.keys(value)
  }
}
```

This will do the job, but you need to add it to your **app.module.ts** as below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ // your different imports
  ],
  declarations: [ // your declarations
    KeysPipe
  ],
  exports: [ // your exports
    KeysPipe
  ]
})
```

Finally in your **component.html** you need to write those lines

```
<P>Avengers</P>
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let value of avengers">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{value.naming}}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let key of value | keys">
      <ng-container *ngIf="key != 'naming'">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let key_second of value[key][0] | keys">
          {{value[key][0][key_second]}}
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion> 
<hr>
```

So like that you have this result

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When you're using:

```
 *ngFor="let x of value.city"
```

then each x you get comprise of an object:

```
{"status":"inactive","age":30}
```

So in your html you have to be more specific i.e:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let x of value.city">
        {{x.status}}
        {{x.age}}
   </ng-container>
```

As for Ironman you'll have to use a different for loop as he doesn't have a registered city, only bio, so your tag for should be something like:

```
let x of value.bio
```

I personally recommend using more descriptive names such as:

```
let avenger of avengers
let bio of avenger.bio
```

etc.

Comment: but cant we get  more in dynamic way with out mentioning the names ?